# Device not returned in list of receivers when using whitelisted application ID

Tags: google-cast

I've seen a couple other questions from others having the same problem: in my sample application I've registered a callback as follows:

```
cast_api.addReceiverListener(appId, onReceiverList);
```

When I use `appId = 'YouTube'` I see my Cast, but when I use the whitelisted app ID here I get an empty list. I have rebooted the Cast and also done a factory reset to make sure the "Send this Chromecast's serial number to Google when checking for updates" is checked; it is.

I am able to connect to the Cast over the debug port.

I am not sure what else I could be missing, besides perhaps:

- mis-spelling the serial number (mine was 7 numbers and 5 letters,
  does that make sense?)
- device has not updated the whitelisted app IDs

Any thoughts? It's really hard to try to figure out what's going on, since there is no way to ensure the device has registered the whitelisted app IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It started working on its own this afternoon. I received the email stating that the app had been whitelisted about 11 hours ago. It seems like there could be a delay between receiving the email and the Cast device retrieving the application IDs.

Comment: Once you get the email that your ID is ready - you can either wait for the device to get the update automatically - or better yet - reboot the device to get the update immediately.

Comment: @PaulCarff In this case, I had rebooted many times and had done a factory reset.