# How are messages sent back and forth between the sender and the receiver?

Tags: google-chrome, google-cast, chromecast

I am trying to build an app where I need to send data from the sender to the receiver after launching the receiver, and also sending messages from the receiver back to the sender.

I have read through the developers guide and the API documentation and looked at some of the examples on GitHub, and it looks like I need to use the ChannelFactory somehow.

I am looking for a good example and explanation on how to achieve this messaging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With thanks to Nick and Les for pointing me in the right direction, I am going to leave an answer here that has code samples.

I have put together a small wrapper framework to make working with Chromecast a little easier.  I hope others find this useful.

EDIT:
[I moved the code samples to github](https://github.com/1985media/chromecast)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's a "good example", but some of the code here might help:

https://github.com/nickspacek/chromecast/tree/gh-pages

Comment: I used Nick's code to get messaging working in my application, so this is a very good starting place.

Comment: It's based off of the Tic Tac Toe sample (the Receiver side anyways)

Comment: I am not seeing the messaging work.  I have put the sample up on my own server and swapped out the appId for my own.

I do not even see the console.debug from line 27 of index.html

Comment: @Fisch It could be that your appId is not activated on the device yet. Have you gone through those steps and made sure to enable it when you first setup the device: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128843/device-not-returned-in-list-of-receivers-when-using-whitelisted-application-id

Comment: The sender app can cast to the receiver without issue, but when I type in the box to "say" something and hit enter, nothing happens other than the input box emptying.  No errors in the console of either the sender or receiver.

Comment: @Fisch Sorry, I read the reply quickly didn't realize you were using that sample app. I'd have to dig into it some. I'm not sure what state that code is at, as I got frustrated with the lack of responses to my requests for clarification and moved onto some other projects.

Comment: thanks for your help.  it provided me guidance and ideas for building a small wrapper framework (which I added as an answer)

Answer (score 1):

The [Tic-Tac-Toe](https://github.com/googlecast/cast-android-tictactoe) sample shows how to do this using your own private protocol.  The sample is for Android, we'll be providing an iOS sample shortly.

Comment: the sender documentation for Chrome Apps under Custom Messages does not have an example and refers to the Receiver Tutorial.  The receiver tutorial makes no mention of custom messages.  When can we expect the documentation to be updated?  Is there a different place where I can find examples of passing custom messages between sender and receiver?

Comment: https://github.com/googlecast/cast-android-tictactoe/blob/master/receiver/tictactoe.html is a place for the Receiver

Comment: thanks for your help.  it provided me guidance and ideas for building a small wrapper framework (which I added as an answer)